# How to derive the Total derivative of function by another function.

Tags: derivatives

I have a question how to find a total derivative $\frac{dP}{d\rho}$ where $P = P(\rho,r,z)$ and $\rho = \rho(r,z)$?

Answer (score 2):

The exterior derivative satisfies (the example has three variables, but it works with any number of variables)

$$ \mathrm{d} f(x, y, z) = f_1(x,y,z) \, \mathrm{d}x + f_2(x,y,z) \, \mathrm{d} x + f_3(x,y,z) \, \mathrm{d} z$$

where $f_1$ means the derivative of $f$ with respect to its first positional argument.

This is true no matter what relationships, if any, there are between $x$, $y$, and $z$, or between them and any other variable.

Thus, you can just compute the derivative mechanically without worrying about what depends on what.

If $\mathrm{d}u$ and $\mathrm{d}v$ happen to be ratios of each other, then $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}u}$ is well-defined and equal to that ratio.

From just the information you've given, there's no reason to think the total derivative you ask for exists. But if we were to assume it does, we can compute it as

$$ \mathrm{d}p(\rho(r,z), r, z) = p_1(\rho(r,z), r, z) \mathrm{d} \rho(r,z) + p_2(\rho(r,z), r, z) \mathrm{d}r + p_3(\rho(r,z), r, z) \mathrm{d} z$$

and so

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}p(\rho(r,z), r, z)}{\mathrm{d} \rho(r,z)} = p_1(\rho(r,z), r, z) + p_2(\rho(r,z), r, z) \frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d} \rho(r,z)} + p_3(\rho(r,z), r, z) \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} \rho(r,z)}$$

and so further calculation depends on your ability to find the other two total derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

$$
P=P(\rho,r,z)
$$
$$
\rho=\rho(r,z)
$$
Mechanically the result is this.
$$
\frac{dP}{d\rho}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial \rho}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial r}\frac{\partial r}{\partial \rho}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \rho}
$$
unfortunately with the given information no further calculation can be performed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the derivative of $P(\rho,r,z)$ with respect to $\rho$, then that is just a partial derivative

$$\frac{\partial P (\rho,r,z)}{\partial \rho}=P_\rho(\rho,r,z)=P_1(\rho,r,z).$$

If you want the derivative of the composition $P(\rho(r,z),r,z)$ with respect to $\rho$, then that is zero because the composition is a function of only $r$ and $z$.